# How to monitor a windows directory using watchdog?

Tags: python-3.x, python-watchdog

I'm trying to watch a directory on System32 with watchdog but it doesn't get any event, if I change the path to a folder on desktop it works.
The folder is with all security permissions allow to everyone.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import (
    PatternMatchingEventHandler, FileModifiedEvent,
    FileCreatedEvent)

observer = Observer()  
class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event: FileCreatedEvent):  
        print('File Created: ', event.src_path)

    def on_modified(self, event: FileModifiedEvent):  
        print('File Modified: %s [%s]' % (
            event.src_path, event.event_type))


observer.schedule(event_handler=Handler('*'), path='C:/Windows/System32/Tpar')  
observer.daemon = False
observer.start()

try:
    observer.join() 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopped.')
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```